# Using Third-Party Modules with Python in an Automator Service

Tags: python, automator

I have installed Py-Appscript on my machine and it can be used with the Python installation at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python`.

I am trying to use this installation of Py-Appscript with an Automator service. To do this, I use the **Run Shell Script** action and then set the **Shell** to `usr/bin/python` (which is my only choice for Python, unfortunately).

The `usr/bin/python` does not appear to have access to my third-party modules and crashes on the line:

`from appscript import *`

Is there a way for me to give `usr/bin/python` access to my third-party modules?
OR
Is there a way to tell Automator to use `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python` instead?

I need Automator to run the Python directly from the **Run Shell Script** action. Any action that calls Python scripts that are external to Automator (via `bin/bash`, for example) does not perform quickly enough to be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I was able to get it working using a hack found at [How do I execute a PHP shell script as an Automator action on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398591/how-do-i-execute-a-php-shell-script-as-an-automator-action-on-mac-os-x).

Inside of the **Run Shell Script** action, I used the `/bin/sh/` shell with `<<EOF` ... `EOF` to the proper Python installation.

So for example, entering

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python <<EOF
from appscript import *
Numbers = app('Numbers')
EOF
```

Into the code section of the **Run Shell Script** action will work. So one can call the proper installation (`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python` above) and put their program between the `<<EOF` ... `EOF` delimeters.

### Alfred

This trick works with Alfred also. If you want to use `appscript` with Alfred, just make sure that you pass `{query}` to the python version above, like this:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python script.py {query}
```

Comment: If you're going to do that then you should just specify that Python executable in the script's shebang line and chmod the script executable.

Comment: I actually tried that already and it ran slower than the above method. I assume the reason is because both methods need to access the `Python.framework` installation from the hard drive but the above method at least doesn't have to access the code from a different hard drive location than the Automator action. So I am thinking the above method requires 2 hard drive retrievals (python and Automator) while the method you are suggesting requires 3 (python, executable .py file, and Automator).

Answer (score 0):

When you install modules, you typically install them per Python instance. So in this case you have installed them for the Python in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python, and it will then be available only for that Python. /usr/bin/python is then apparently another Python installation (I'm not an OS X expert).

To make it available for the /usr/bin/python installation, install it for /usr/bin/python.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, I installed appscript using `sudo easy_install appscript` in Terminal and I have no idea how to redirect it to install for `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: Okay, I was able to attempt to install appscript for `/usr/bin/python` using:

`sudo /usr/bin/python -m easy_install appscript`

However, this encountered the error:

`unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory`

Leaving me back at square one, unfortunately. Given this, it looks like my best bet is somehow getting Automator to use `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python`

Comment: I actually have Xcode installed already. I'm an iPhone developer.

Comment: Normal command is `sudo /usr/bin/easy_install appscript`, but yours should work as well. Perhaps something's wonky with your shell profile or you've changed something in your system? The built-in Python requires gcc-4.2 to build extensions, which comes with Xcode3.2. If you've installed an older Xcode or have changed your gcc setup then that might be the reason it can't find [presumably] gcc-4.2.