# How to start/run Python script automatically when file is downloaded (macOS)

Tags: python, bash, macos, python-watchdog

I have written a script which uses watchdog to organize files into folders when they are downloaded, that is added to the Download folder. However, it only works if I manually start running the script and then add files to the Download folder. Is there a way that I can start the script automatically whenever the a file is downloaded without me having run the script in the terminal manually?

This is what the script looks like:

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
import time
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import os
import json

class HandleDownloads(FileSystemEventHandler):
    #observer.schedule runs on_modified()
    def on_modified(self, event):
        try:
            for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
                src= folder_to_track + "/" + filename
                if ("U10" in filename):
                    new_destination = "/Users/user1/Documents/Studies/DDDC91" + "/" + filename
                    os.rename(src, new_destination)
        except:
            pass



folder_to_track = "/Users/user1/Downloads"

event_handler = HandleDownloads()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_to_track, recursive = True)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
```

UPDATE:

I have figured out that I will need to add it to the Automator. But get stuck at this step:

[image: Automator with]

I don't know how to run the script using "/usr/bin/python" as shown in the image. I also tried "/bin/bash" with:

```
 cd Documents
 python organize_downloads.py
```

But this did not work either as it would give error on the imports.

Comment: add the script to computer startup? then it would always be running when a file got downloaded.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do this? I can't seem to find much on it, all I found was that using Automator might be useful. However, Automator only seem to run Apple scripts or Java scripts, not Python. @AlanHoover

Comment: I haven't done it on a mac.  In windows you add it to startup.  In linux you put it in rc.d / init.d.  Googling those terms should get you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your *Run Shell Script* automator step is mixed up a bit.
It uses shell-commands like `cd Folder` and `python script.py` with the Python shell. I would decide for one of the shells, and then stick to it most explicitly. So you can:

#### either run it as regular Shell script with `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`:

```sh
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python ~/Documents/organize_downloads.py
```

Note: the path to python interpreter must be absolute (as shown above).
Maybe also the path to your script must be absolute (`Documents` relative to your user's home folder `~` as above).

#### or as Python script with `/usr/bin/python`:

```py
# contents of your script file pasted directly here as python code
```

#### See also

- [Error using OSX Automator, Python, and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725808/error-using-osx-automator-python-and-beautifulsoup)
- [Using Third-Party Modules with Python in an Automator Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093837/using-third-party-modules-with-python-in-an-automator-service)