# How to drag image into Mac app?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm building a Mac app. I want to be able to drag an image into my app and then press a button to resize the image into a smaller dimension. Then, I will export the image back to the original folder it came from. (Similar to the app Prepo)

Comment: I have years of iOS experience, but this is my first Mac app. I found a bash script to resize the images: https://gist.github.com/837916
I just need to know how to drag in image into the window, access it programmatically, and run the script on it (if it's possible to run a bash script from Xcode.) This app will be used internally, not on the App Store if that matters.

Comment: If that's all you need the application for, you could do this very simply with Automator, kind of [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398591/how-do-i-execute-a-php-shell-script-as-an-automator-action-on-mac-os-x/1621289#1621289)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Drag and Drop Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html).

> Cocoa gives you the ability to implement sophisticated drag-and-drop
>   capabilities both within your application and between applications.
>   This programming topic describes how you can implement drag-and-drop
>   with just a few methods.